# Where the offset in a file is stored in C?

Tags: c

In which place C saves file's offset?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. The file offset is just a variable that's part of a struct. It isn't saved.

Comment: This question makes sense (even a little bit bad formulated but hey guys it was his/her first question). The question is if C stores the file offset in the FILE structure or in the INode (or whatever you call it on windows). And it is stored in the FILE structure and synchronized on flush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using standard C I/O, a `FILE` pointer contains most of the information needed to deal with the file, including its "position indicator." As you read or write through the file, its position (seek) indicator gets updated. See the [definition of the `FILE` type](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/FILE/).